# Linking In Dependencies of a Shared Library

Tags: c++, linker

I created a library that I'd like others to use.

To Compile My library:

```
 /usr/bin/g++ -fPIC -shared -Wl,-soname,libMYLIB.so [inputs] -lboost_system -lboost_thread
```

To Compile a Binary:

```
/usr/bin/g++ myTest.cpp -lMYLIB -lboost_system
```

I would like that line to only be:

```
/usr/bin/g++ myTest.cpp -lMYLIB
```

How do I avoid having to specify my libraries dependencies later? What flag in the linker or compiler am I looking for?

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "your dependencies later"?  It seems to me, your desired line is only accomplished by directly compiling in the boost libraries into your library, which you cannot do.

Comment: Apologies but I disagree. Some symbols are resolved at MYLIB's link time. I'd simply like to resolve ALL symbols at MYLIB's link time. Notice how I don't have to link boost_thread

Comment: The only way a symbol will be resolved at runtime is if it's signature and location is known.  The `-lboost_system` most likely does not need to list the `-lboost_thread` library because it knows the "extern" interface and finds the thread library by default.  To test it, move the `boost_thread` library out of the `$LD_LIBRARY_PATH`.

Comment: Obviously moving the ```boost_thread``` library out of the run time search paths will fail. I am not looking for how to avoid run time dependency. I am looking how to avoid link time dependency.

Comment: @jiveturkey: How did whoever built `libboost_system.so` tell it to go looking for `libboost_thread`?  Does this happen when the linker creates the .so, or does some code call `dlopen` or equivalent, e.g., in an init function?  Note that it doesn't require `LD_PRELOAD`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a linker option (I mean `ld` linker http://linux.die.net/man/1/ld) --unresolved-symbols=ignore-all or -unresolved-symbols=ignore-in-object-files:

> ```
> Determine how to handle unresolved symbols. There are four possible values for method: 
>
> * ignore-all 
>     Do not report any unresolved symbols. 
> * report-all 
>     Report all unresolved symbols. This is the default. 
> * ignore-in-object-files 
>     Report unresolved symbols that are contained in shared libraries, but ignore them if they come from regular object files. 
> * ignore-in-shared-libs 
>     Report unresolved symbols that come from regular object files, but ignore them if they come from shared libraries. This can be useful
> ```
>
> when creating a dynamic binary and it is known that all the shared
>   libraries that it should be referencing are included on the linker's
>   command line.

And this is an example. I have a library `libmylib.so` and an application `main`:

So first I build the library:

```
$ g++ -fpic  -shared mylib.cpp -o libmylib.so
```

When I build the application but I do not add -lmylib on command line. Normally it results in error `Unresolved external symbols` but since I add `-Wl,--unresolved-symbols=ignore-in-object-files` to the command line I get no errors:

```
$ g++ -fpic -g main.cpp -Wl,--unresolved-symbols=ignore-in-object-files  -Wl,-rpath,.
```

Then I run my program:

```
$ ./a.out 
./a.out: symbol lookup error: ./a.out: undefined symbol: _Z7my_funcd
```

It doesn't work as expected but then I use LD_PRELOAD:

```
$ LD_PRELOAD=./libmylib.so ./a.out                                                   
2
```

So with LD_PRELOAD it works

Comment: This is great! Is it possible to have ```ignore-in-shared-libs``` baked into the creation of the shared library? Your example uses the linker option during the executable creation, I'd like to use the option during the shared library creaton.

Comment: You can use "ignore-all" but it seems if one builds a library with "gcc -shared" it is not necessary since `gcc` does not complain about unresolved symbols